# Converting upper case to lowercase assembly TASM

Tags: assembly

I want to convert uppercase to lowercase in assembly TASM and I wrote the following code. The text is in `stdin` and it has max 100 characters. 
It should output the text and show the number of characters read, but when I try to  put  the  input from the keyboard it won't work:

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
SIR DB 100 DUP (?)
newline DB 10,13,'$'
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA, ES:DATA

; procedura de conversie

fctie PROC FAR
; IF AL<'A'
    cmp     al, 'A'
JB iesire
; IF AL>'Z'
    cmp     al, 'Z'
JA iesire
    ADD     AL, 20H

iesire: RET
fctie ENDP

START PROC FAR

    PUSH    DS
    XOR     AX,AX
    PUSH    AX
    MOV     AX,DATA
    MOV     DS,AX
    MOV     ES,AX


        MOV     BL, 0
        MOV     DI, OFFSET SIR
        cld

    ;citirea unui caracter din sir
    L1:
        MOV     AH, 01H
        INT     21H

    ;vf dc e caracterul space
        CMP     AL, ' '
    JE increment

        CMP     AL, '$'
    JE auxL2

    CALL fctie
    ; ca sa evitam intrarea automata in increment 
    JMP auxL
    increment: INC BL
    auxL:

    ;rescrierea caracterului in lowercase
    ;-instructions equiv to stosb
    ;MOV ES:[DI], AL 
    ;INC DI
    STOSB

    auxL2:
    ;vf. dc e sf. de sir
        CMP     AL, '$' 
    LOOPNE L1

    ; linie noua
        LEA     DX, newline
        MOV     AH, 09H
        INT     21H

    ;afisare 
        mov     DX, offset SIR
        MOV     AH, 09H
        INT     21H

    ; afisare nr de cuvinte
        ADD     BL, 01
        MOV     DL, BL
        MOV     AH, 02H
        ADD     DL, 30h; convertire in string pentru ca nr sa afiseze: 30H e val lui 0 hexa in ASCII
        INT     21H

    ;iesire program
        MOV     AH, 4CH
        INT     21H
    START ENDP
    CODE ENDS
    END START
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to watch what is going on?

Comment: yes but I don't see where the problem is

Comment: _"it won't work"_ is too vague a problem description. What exactly does not work, and what does it do instead?

Comment: This is quite a bit of assembly to wade through in order to help find the bug. Can you cut this down to the bare minimum to isolate the problem?  Also, perhaps translate the comments (even automatically) to English to help engage the broadest possible audience.

Comment: Since you used a debugger already, you already know something about where the problem *isn't*, so you can include that in your question to save everyone else some time.  I didn't actually downvote (yet), but see http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ for more about why this is important.  Also why a [mcve] is important.  BTW, to case-flip a single ASCII alphabetic character in AL, use `xor al, 0x20` to flip the right bit.

Comment: I would also say put something in like a single data item (like "A") and then just try converting that to "a". THEN do the STDIN. Remember - that you should always reduce your problem to the smallest amount and then increase as you go.